# How does one define the country objectClass in an LDIF file?

Tags: ldap

I need to have the following dn format: c=,o=organisation,dc=xxx,dc=net
and I have defined the following ldif file:

```
dn: c=France,o=BMP,dc=myComp,dc=net
c: FR
objectClass: c
description: French officies
```

but ldapAdd says there is something wrong with that ldif file outputting the following error:

```
ldap_add: Invalid syntax (21) additional info: objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`c` is not an `objectClass`, it is an attribute. The entry should contain an `objectClass` that permits the `c` attribute, for example:

```
dn: c=France,o=BMP,dc=myComp,dc=net
c: FR
objectClass: country
objectClass: top
description: French officies
```

#### see also

- [RFC4519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-3.2)